# Using scipy.stats to fit xarray DataArray

Tags: python, scipy, dask, python-xarray

I want to compute the parameters of a statistical distribution fitted over the time dimension of an xarray.DataArray.

I'd like to create a function that does something like:

```
from scipy import stats
import xarray as xr

def fit(arr):
    return xr.apply_ufunc(stats.norm.fit, arr, ...)
```

that returns a new DataArray storing the two parameters of the distribution computed over the time dimension. So if an input has dimensions (time, lat, lon), fit would return a DataArray with dimensions (params, lat, lon). The next step would be to use these parameters to compute various percentiles (e.g. stats.norm.ppf).

After many unsuccessful trials, I'm doubting apply_ufunc supports this use case and that I should rather do the computation using

```
params = np.apply_along_axis(stats.norm.fit, arr.get_axis_num('time'), arr.data)
```

then create the DataArray manually, copying dimensions and attributes.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

---

Here is what I ended up doing, which feels a bit like a hack:

```
# Fit the parameters (lazy computation)
data = dask.array.apply_along_axis(dc.fit, arr.get_axis_num('time'), arr)

# Create a DataArray with the desired dimensions to copy them over to the parameter array.
mean = arr.mean(dim='time', keep_attrs=True)
coords = dict(mean.coords.items())
coords['dparams'] = ([] if dc.shapes is None else dc.shapes.split(',')) + ['loc', 'scale']
out = xr.DataArray(data=data, coords=coords, dims=(u'dparams',) + mean.dims)
out.attrs = arr.attrs
```

Comment: Is the normal distribution the only distribution that you want to fit, or did you use that just as an example of *some* distribution?

Comment: Just an example, I'd like to be able to select any distribution from scipy' list.

Comment: did you have any luck on this? I am trying to use the testing functions in sp.stats. and i get a cryptic ValueError: indexes along dimension 'dim' are not equal

Answer (score 1):

Dask array includes an analogue of [apply_along_axis](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.apply_along_axis), may be the most obvious place to start. Note that each variable of an xarray that has chunks set automatically encapsulate a dask array in the `.data` attribute. You may even be able to pass the xarray variable directly.

Comment: Thanks, I can indeed pass the xarray variable directly, and get the resulting array. I'm still losing however the "Dataset" information (dimensions, metadata, etc).